# How to call multiple GET methods from the same api controller in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, http-get

I am using asp.net mvc5 and webapi 2. Here is my sample controller -

```
public class DataFetchController : ApiController
{
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetDO()
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse("ok");
    }

    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetDoes()
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse("ok");
    }
 }
```

In my WebApiConfig.cs file I have the following code -

```
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
```

When I run this project and try to browse "api/DataFetch/getdo" link then i encountered an error that shows -

> {"$id":"1","Message":"An error has
>   occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Multiple actions were found that match
>   the request: \r\nGetDO on type
>   MagicMeter.Controllers.DataFetchController\r\nGetDoes on type
>   MagicMeter.Controllers.DataFetchController","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","StackTrace":"
>   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionSelector.ActionSelectorCacheItem.SelectAction(HttpControllerContext
>   controllerContext)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionSelector.SelectAction(HttpControllerContext
>   controllerContext)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.ApiController.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext
>   controllerContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()"}

How can I fix this problem??

Comment: This is because how REST in WebApi works.  You don't need to use REST as the provided answer shows (where you instead need to specify the action in the url instead of the http verb), but with the route as per the question, the `action` is determined by the http verb, in this case `GET`.  As there's only one verb (GET), there's only one action which is determined automatically (or by tags) by the name "Get*".  You can have multiple actions by having different overloads (eg `GetAll()` and `Get(id)`) but not if they have the same signature.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your route config code to this

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: should i add this as new routes.maphttproute or i would edit the existing one?

Comment: You can do either one. In case if you want to add this as new route, change name because DefaultAPI is already used.

Comment: It should be noted that this will mean your API is not RESTful.  But as your Q already includes the action, it looks like you're not using REST, so should be ok *in this case*.